# Inheritiance __init__ from classes in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

So I can't seem to figure out how to inherit the `__init__` from my classes.
I am trying to make an RPG by myself, and I just recently learned that using inheritance for making my enemies, characters and stuff like that was a better idea.
So I started using it for enemies but ran into a problem with the **init** method.
This is my Enemy Class:

```
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, number_of, name):
        self.number_of = int(number_of)
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 20 * self.number_of
        self.dmg = 2 * self.number_of
    def attack(self, player):
        dmg = 0
        player.hp -= dmg
    def appearing(self):
        if self.number_of > 1:
            print (f"{self.number_of} {self.name}s have appeared")
        else:
            print(f"A {self.name} has appeared")
```

And i tried different ways to make the specific enemy classes. I will just leave the methods, because they work fine for me, and focus in the **init** of my class.
So first I tried doing it like this:

```
class Orc():
    def __init__(self):
        Enemy.__init__(self,number_of, name)
```

But Python makes it a type error:
TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

I also tried putting self in front of number_of and name, but the same error came out.

Then I tried putting in arguments in the original **init**:

```
class Orc():
def __init__(self, number_of,name):
    Enemy.__init__(self,self.number_of, self.name)
```

But that just resulted in an Attribute error:

AttributeError: 'Orc' object has no attribute 'number_of'

I then tried putting self. in front of the **init**, but then there was a syntaxerror.

I just ended up doing different **init** for each class (each type of enemy), without even using the **init** in the parent (Enemy) class.

So what am I doing wrong, and what can I do instead, to actually use the **init** method in the parent class, and save some code

Comment: I don't see any inheritance.

Comment: okay, so it does work now.I am so confused, I must have deleted it at some point at the start of my many tries. anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to actually inherit from the `Enemy` class in your `Orc` class, then you can simply call `super()`:

```
class Orc(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, number_of, name):
        super().__init__(number_of, name)
```

`self` is automatically passed to the class when you call super.

Comment: You don't have to override `__init__` at all if you just want it to be the same as in the base class.

Comment: @khelwood That's true but I assumed OP would be doing something else in the `Orc` class's `__init__`.